# Running Electron on windows: Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed

Tags: node.js, electron, aws-sdk

I am trying to the run an electron app on windows that uses `aws-crt`. Everything works fine on MacOS.

But in windows, I get this error:

```
App threw an error during load
Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
\\?\C:\Code\mir-kiosk-electron\electron-kiosk\node_modules\aws-crt\dist\bin\win32-x64\aws-crt-nodejs.node
    at process.func [as dlopen] (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:1846)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:18)
    at Object.func [as .node] (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:1846)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:935:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:14)
    at Function.f._load (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:12684)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Code\mir-kiosk-electron\electron-kiosk\.webpack\main\index.js:8461:19)
    at Object../node_modules/aws-crt/dist/native/binding.js (C:\Code\mir-kiosk-electron\electron-kiosk\.webpack\main\index.js:8470:30)
webpack built f8189be91ec9475472dc in 1864ms
```

What should I do?

I found a similar issue in https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/11853.

It says I need to rebuild the node module.

I have already done
`.\node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild.cmd`
The error is still there.

Here is my package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "aws-crt": "^1.7.1",
    "aws-iot-device-sdk-v2": "^1.5.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "jimp": "^0.16.1",
    "pixelmatch": "^5.2.1",
    "pngjs": "^6.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  }
```

My gut feeling is I need to rebuild `aws-crt` for electron. But how do I do it?

Comment: anyone can help?

Comment: Hi, I am stuck at trying to rebuild `aws-crt` After looking at the debug log. I can see that some help `aws-crt` is skipped.  Why is it?